# Compare 2 files on specific row only

Tags: awk, grep

I need to compare 2 files and find the matching rows.
The only problem is that I need to check the 4th row out of 5 from DocumentList file and return the entire line if a match is found in final file.

```
cat DocumentList.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> <block-list:block-list xmlns:block-list="http://openoffice.org/2001/block-list">
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="adn" block-list:name="and" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="tesst" block-list:name="test" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="tust" block-list:name="test" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="seme" block-list:name="same"/>
```

And the second file is:

```
cat final.txt
and
test
india
```

---

I can extract the forth row using this command, but do not know how to compare with the lines from final file

```
awk -F '\"' '{print $4}' DocumentList.xml
```

Expected Result:

```
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="adn" block-list:name="and" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="tesst" block-list:name="test" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="tust" block-list:name="test" />
```

I have also tried something like this, but it does not return the entire line from DocumetList file.

```
awk -F '\"' 'FNR==NR {a[$4]; next} $1 in a'  DocumentList.xml final.txt
```

final.txt file is 1 GB, DocumentList is 25 MB and both have unicode characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just swap the order of reading files:

```
awk -F '\"' 'FNR==NR {a[$0]; next} $4 in a' final.txt DocumentList.xml
```

Output:

```
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="adn" block-list:name="and" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="tesst" block-list:name="test" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="tust" block-list:name="test" />
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr1[$0]
  next
}
match($0,/block-list:name="([^"]*)"/,arr2) && (arr2[1] in arr1)
' final.txt DocumentList.xml
```

***Explanation:*** In `awk` program reading both the Input_file(s) named `final.txt` and `DocumentList.xml`. Then in main program using condition `FNR==NR` which will be TRUE when final.txt is being read. In  that condition block I am creating an array named arr1 whose index is current line and then using `next` will skip all further statements from there onwards. Then I have used `match` function of `awk`, which matches regex mentioned in it(`block-list:name="([^"]*)"`) this matches everything from `block-list:name=` followed by a `"` till next occurrence of `"` comes keep in mind `()` creates values and stores them into array named `arr2` which we will access later on. Then using `&& (arr2[1] in arr1)` condition to check if value of arr2's 1st element comes in array arr1 then print that line(basically matching values of final.txt and needed value from DocumentList.xml).

Answer (score 1):

you can try,

```
search=$(awk 'BEGIN{OFS=ORS=""}{if(NR>1){print "|"}print $1;}' final.txt)
# store 'and|test|india' in search variable

grep -E "block-list:name=\"($search)\"" DocumentList.xml
```

you get,

```
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="adn" block-list:name="and" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="tesst" block-list:name="test" />
<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="tust" block-list:name="test" />
```

Or using, 'awk'

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="block-list:name=\""}
     FNR==NR {a[$1]; next} {f=$2;gsub(/".*/,"",f)} 
     FNR>1 && f in a{print $0}
' final.txt DocumentList.xml
```

Note: for xml files, I don't recommend how you are doing it, is better to use xml-parser